# CSS jQuery - Having bullet points as indicators in my slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a slider with jQuery. But there is still a thing missing, I want indicators so the user can switch between the images. This should be possible through the `.bullet-points` and the `.thumbnails img`

I don't really find an approach with my special markup, how can I do that?

Here is the code

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/yXboEV

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var images = [$(".image-holder img:first-child"), $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".image-holder img:last-child")];
  var thumbnails = [$(".thumbnails img:first-child"), $(".thumbnails img:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".thumbnails img:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".thumbnails img:last-child")];
  var text = [$(".text-holder .text:first-child"), $(".text-holder .text:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".text-holder .text:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".text-holder .text:last-child")];
  var backgrounds = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "grey"];

  i = 1;
  var time = 3000;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (i != 0) {
      images[i - 1].removeClass("active");
      text[i - 1].removeClass("active");
      thumbnails[i - 1].removeClass("active-thumbnail");
    }
    if (i == images.length) {
      i = 0
    }
    images[i].addClass("active");
    text[i].addClass("active");
    thumbnails[i].addClass("active-thumbnail");
    $(".slider").css("background-color", backgrounds[i]);
    i++;

  }, time);

});
```

```css
.text-holder p {
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
  /*background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHzNrZnq-4-FItozqSu2ZWCBXW4LjWKTlkOOgDlZFj-JtdTuclVQ');*/
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.thumbnails {
  height: 100%;
}

.thumbnails img {
  max-width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-holder .text {
  display: none;
}


/*display active image*/

.active {
  display: block!important;
}


/*hide thumbnail when image is active*/

.active-thumbnail {
  display: none!important;
}

.bullet-points {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.bullet-points a {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*.image-holder{
      max-width: 350px!important;
    }
    
    .image-holder img{
      max-width: 350px!important;
    }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="image-holder">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993474/money_gsliha.jpg" style="display:none;" class="active">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993472/rap_zduqat.jpg" style="display:none;">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/rauch_oikfed.jpg" style="display:none;">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/girls_x07ay8.jpg" style="display:none;">
        </div>
        <div class="bullet-points">
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnails">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993474/money_gsliha.jpg" class="active-thumbnail">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993472/rap_zduqat.jpg">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/rauch_oikfed.jpg">
          <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/girls_x07ay8.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="text-holder">
          <div class="text active">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <h1>Giant Heading 1</h1>
            <p>Some more text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <h1>Giant Heading 2</h1>
            <p>Some more text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <h1>Giant Heading 3</h1>
            <p>Some more text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <h1>Giant Heading 4</h1>
            <p>Some more text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

Create a slider function instead of using as an anonymous function like in your current code.

Bind an on click event to the `.thumbnails img` and `.bullet-points a` and you can control the logic in that event.

Create a variable to control current slide so when user jumping from slide to slide, the slideshow shows correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var images = [$(".image-holder img:first-child"), $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".image-holder img:last-child")];
  var thumbnails = [$(".thumbnails img:first-child"), $(".thumbnails img:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".thumbnails img:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".thumbnails img:last-child")];
  var text = [$(".text-holder .text:first-child"), $(".text-holder .text:nth-of-type(2)"), $(".text-holder .text:nth-of-type(3)"), $(".text-holder .text:last-child")];
  var backgrounds = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "grey"];

  var i = 0;
  var currentSlide = 0;
  var time = 3000;
  var sliderTimer = setInterval(slider, time);


  // slider navigation
  $('.bullet-points a, .thumbnails img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pos = $(this).index();
    clearInterval(sliderTimer); // stop auto slideshow
    sliderTimer = false;
    slider(pos);
  });

  function slider(pos) {
    currentSlide = i;
    if (typeof(pos) !== 'undefined') {
      i = pos;
      images[currentSlide - 1].removeClass("active");
      text[currentSlide - 1].removeClass("active");
      thumbnails[currentSlide - 1].removeClass("active-thumbnail");
    }
    if (i != 0) {
      images[i - 1].removeClass("active");
      text[i - 1].removeClass("active");
      thumbnails[i - 1].removeClass("active-thumbnail");
    }
    if (i == images.length) { i = 0 }
    images[i].addClass("active");
    text[i].addClass("active");
    thumbnails[i].addClass("active-thumbnail");
    $(".slider").css("background-color", backgrounds[i]);
    i++;
    if (!sliderTimer) {
      sliderTimer = setInterval(slider, time); // start auto slideshow
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.text-holder p{margin: 0;}
.slider{
  padding:20px;
  margin: 50px;
  /*background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHzNrZnq-4-FItozqSu2ZWCBXW4LjWKTlkOOgDlZFj-JtdTuclVQ');*/
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.thumbnails{
  height: 100%;
}

.thumbnails img{
  max-width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-holder .text{
  display: none;
}

/*display active image*/

.active{
  display: block!important;
}

/*hide thumbnail when image is active*/

.active-thumbnail{
  display: none!important;
}

.bullet-points{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.bullet-points a{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

/*.image-holder{
  max-width: 350px!important;
}

.image-holder img{
  max-width: 350px!important;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993474/money_gsliha.jpg" style="display:none;" class="active">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993472/rap_zduqat.jpg" style="display:none;">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/rauch_oikfed.jpg" style="display:none;">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/girls_x07ay8.jpg" style="display:none;">
          </div>
          <div class="bullet-points">
            <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
            <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
            <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
            <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="thumbnails">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993474/money_gsliha.jpg" class="active-thumbnail">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993472/rap_zduqat.jpg">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/rauch_oikfed.jpg">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/somestuff/image/upload/v1497993471/girls_x07ay8.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="text-holder">
            <div class="text active">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h1>Giant Heading 1</h1>
              <p>Some more text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h1>Giant Heading 2</h1>
              <p>Some more text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h1>Giant Heading 3</h1>
              <p>Some more text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h1>Giant Heading 4</h1>
              <p>Some more text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you also know how to stop the slide for like 10 seconds when the user clicks on a thumbnail or bullet item?

Comment: Thank You. I have a new question, maybe you can help here, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678640/jquery-css-slider-swipe-animation?noredirect=1#comment76341589_44678640