# jQuery how to change the value of keyframes from - to with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a slider with a little animation.

I want to add play a keyframe each 6 seconds or something like that. The keyframe changes the margin of the container where I have my images, so they get visible. But how can I change the keyframes values

```
@keyframes slide-img{
  from {margin-left: -310px;}
  to {margin-left: -620px;}
}
```

by jQuery?

I thought it would be possible like this:

```
var animation = $(".slide-img");

animation.css({"from": "margin-left", "-310px";"to":"margin-left", "-620px"});
```

**You can view the full code here:**

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/awymJZ

(I commented my animation.css(...) because it stopped the animation.

By the way, later I want to achieve that the user can click the bullet points/thumbnails and it slides to the image. Would this be possible with changing the img source or is there an easier way?

Because if the slide is currently at the first bullet point and the user clicks on the 4th bullet point, I don't want to make an animation from image 1 to 2, to 3, to 4 - just from 1 to 4. The only way this might be possible is by changing the img source I think. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Try to read this article, you will get clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152925/using-jquery-to-set-css-keyframe

Comment: Instead of changing a single animation dynamically, have two animations and change the `animation: name` property of the element from the jquery. This would be easy I think

Comment: But how should this work when I have 4 images I want to slide?